# Validating forms with axios vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js, axios, http-status-code-422

I'm trying to send some form data to my backend, but validation with Laravel isn't returning errors with 422 status.

**Axios**

Simple axios post request to a URL and looking to get a response back if we catch an error during request cycle.

```
axios.post(this.formURL, formData)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

**Laravel**

I have set up Laravel Validation to validate some form inputs and return 422 if validation fails.

```
try {
      $this->validate(request(), [
        'chapter_id' => 'required',
        'brother_id' => 'required'
      ]);

      Minute::forceCreate(request());

      return response()->json([
          'status' => 'success',
          'message'    => 'Minute Created',
      ], 201);
  }
  catch (ValidationException $exception) {
      return response()->json([
          'status' => 'error',
          'message'    => 'Error',
          'errors' => $exception->errors(),
      ], 422);
}
```

**Response**

A response is given, but I get **undefined** in console when I try to console it out:

```
{
   "status":"error",
   "message":"Error",
   "errors":{
      "brother_id":[
         "The brother_id field is required."
      ],
      "chapter_id":[
         "The chapter_id field is required."
      ]
   }
}
```

I have come across this issue here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-398269712 but was unable to get past this using their resolution methods. Has anyone come across this issue before? Could this be authentication relation (not likely), that's the last thing I implemented.

**Resolution**

This issue resolved. While implementing axios interceptor to catch authentication errors, I did not return the errors back to the Promise.

```
  axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
    if ( error.response.status == 401 ) {
      store.commit('logout')
      router.push('/login')
    }

    return Promise.reject(error)
  })
```

`return Promise.reject(error)` was missing. **Thanks for your help guys!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the message is quite clear ("The chapter_id field is required."). It seems that the problem is not the result of axios, but that the relevant data values ​​are not passed on to the server. Please check whether the data is transmitted to server by using

```
return $ request;
```

command on server side (start of your controller). If the data is not transmitted, check the front-end carefully. If the data is transmitted try to change scope.

```
try {
  $this->validate(request(), [
    'chapter_id' => 'required',
    'brother_id' => 'required'
  ]);
}
catch (ValidationException $exception) {
  return response()->json([
      'status' => 'error',
      'message'    => 'Error',
      'errors' => $exception->errors(),
  ], 422);
}
Minute::forceCreate(request());

return response()->json([
     'status' => 'success',
     'message'    => 'Minute Created',
], 201);
```

So debug it.

Comment: I am getting a proper response back https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49rw.png

Comment: I edited my answer please try this. and share server response with us.

Comment: I will be happy if you mark my answer as valid. Happy coding @sogeniusio